# Filter List without iteration

Tags: java, collections, filter

Is it possible in Java to filter a List based on some criteria without iteration? I have a List of size 10000 full of beans where those beans have a property of type boolean. If I want to filter that list based on that boolean property is it necessary to iterate the whole List or there is some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, without using an `Iterator`, then the answer is Yes.  For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ) {
    MyElement element = list.get(i);
    if (element.getMyProperty()) {
        list.remove(i);
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Depending on the `List` implementation, this could be an expensive way of implementing filtering than using an `Iterator` and `Iterator.remove()`.  (For instance, if list is a `LinkedList` then `list.get(i)` and `list.remove(i)` are both `O(N)` and hence the list filtering is `O(N^2)`.  By contrast, filtering the same list with an `Iterator` would be `O(N)`.)

---

However, if you are asking if you can filter your list without checking each element in the list, then the answer is No.  You'd need some secondary data structure, or the list to be ordered on the property to achieve better than `O(N)` filtering.

Comment: There's still iteration going on, even if there is no `Iterator`.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen C. Your provided example however iterate that list. I don't understand what kind of expensive implementation you are taking about. Can you provide any web-link or example?

Comment: @Tapas: for example, calling `get(int)` on a `LinkedList` will have to iterate at most half the list to find the element, using an `Iterator` would be more efficient in this case. Read [the JavaDoc of `RandomAccess`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) for some discussion on this topic.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I didn't see that. I will remove my previous comment. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You've got a list of 10000 things and you want to magically be able to select some of them by some criteria without actually going to each one in turn and seeing if it matches the criteria? Ummm... no. You might be able to find a library which will hide the iteration from you, but ultimately you're going to have to visit each item to see if it matches or not.

Comment: Another alternative is to do some up-front work: If you have an index (possibly in the form of two separate `List` objects, on for `true`, the other for `false`), then it's faster (actually the time spent will be transferred to updates, but if you read often this can pay off). It's basically what databases do.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a wrapper class that implements the List interface and just "hides" all beans with the said property. However a lot of operations (e.g. every index based function) would be very inefficient, so it depends what exactly you want to do with the "filtered" List.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using stream in Java 8. Assume you have a list of electric and non-electric cars and you want to extract only electric:

```
List<Car> electricCars= cars.stream().filter(c -> c.isElectric()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```